# Reverse Engineer Flash to find out font name?

Tags: flash, fonts, reverse-engineering

I need to find out the font name from a flash site. Is there an application that can do this for me?

**Thank you!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could load this flash into your own flash movie and use `Font.enumerateFonts()`  ([docs](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/text/Font.html)) to see which fonts are embedded. But the programmer may use another than the original name.

If you have i.e. FlashDevelop, there is an option in the project tree, to expand an swf file, which will show you all embedded classes, symbols and also fonts.

Comment: I found the fonts' names with FlashDevelop! Awesome, thank you!!

Answer (score 2):

You can better take a screenshot and use this service: http://new.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/

Answer (score 1):

It isn't a programming answer, but I would try making a screenshot and upload that to [WhatTheFont](http://new.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/). Helped me sometimes.